# mvnw: Permission denied on JHipster spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jhipster

When I try to clone and run jHipster spring boot application using `./mvnw` command, it getting an error `mvnw: Permission denied`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you checked if the file is executable? Try `chmod +x mvnw` and try again.

Answer (score 8):

if you use dockerfile, you should add `chmod +x mvnw`

```
RUN chmod +x mvnw
```